# How to make some of these fields mandatory (php)?

Tags: php

I'm trying to customize a php script to make it adapted to my needs.
Here's the code :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $error = '';

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if($name=='' || $email=='')
    {
        $error = 'Name and email are mandatory';
    }

    if ($error == '')
    {
        $custom_field1 = $_POST['custom_field1'];
        $custom_field2 = $_POST['custom_field2'];
        $custom_field3 = $_POST['custom_field3'];
        $boolean = 'true';

        $postdata = http_build_query(
            array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'custom_field1' => $custom_field1,
            'custom_field2' => $custom_field2,
            'custom_field3' => $custom_field3,
            'list' => $list,
            'boolean' => 'true'
            )
        );

        $opts = array('http' => array('method'  => 'POST', 'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'content' => $postdata));
        $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
        $result = file_get_contents($app_url.'/signin', false, $context);

        if ($result != 1)
            $error = $result;
    }
} 
?>
```

By default the name and the email are the two mandatory fields, i would like the custom fields 1 & 2 to be mandatory as well.

I'd also like the error message to be specific to the missing field(s).
With the current code, even if the name is filled, the message says :

> Name and email are mandatory

Thanks

Comment: separate the conditions, also mandatory means to not continue the script... use die/exit

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $custom_field1 = $_POST['custom_field1'];
    $custom_field2 = $_POST['custom_field2'];
    $error = array();

    if($name=='')
    {
        $error[] = 'Name are mandatory';
    }

    if($email == '')
    {
        $error[] = 'Email are mandatory';
    }

    if($custom_field1 == '')
    {
        $error[] = 'Custom field 1 is mandatory';
    }

    if($custom_field2 == '')
    {
        $error[] = 'Custom field 2 is mandatory';
    }

    if (!empty($error))
    {
        $custom_field3 = $_POST['custom_field3'];
        $boolean = 'true';

        $postdata = http_build_query(
            array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'custom_field1' => $custom_field1,
            'custom_field2' => $custom_field2,
            'custom_field3' => $custom_field3,
            'list' => $list,
            'boolean' => 'true'
            )
        );

        $opts = array('http' => array('method'  => 'POST', 'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'content' => $postdata));
        $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
        $result = file_get_contents($app_url.'/signin', false, $context);

        if ($result != 1)
            $error[] = $result;
    }
}
```

When you displaying the error messages, make a loop in `$error` array

```
foreach ($error as $errstr)
{
    echo "<p>{$errstr}</p>";
}
```

or `implode` to string and echoes like

```
echo "<p>" . implode("</p><p>", $error) . "</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This block says `if` name is empty `||` (or) email is empty the `error` is "Name and email are mandatory".

```
if($name=='' || $email=='') {
    $error = 'Name and email are mandatory';
}
```

If you would like to create seperate error messages, just follow this pattern. I'm sure you will figure it out if you give it a try.

Comment: Ok, let's say i want the $custom_field1 to be mandatory as well, should I add `$custom_field1 = $_POST['custom_field1'];` before the if statement ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `if` statement with a custom error for each field you'd like to check:

```
if ($name == '')
{
    $error = 'Name is mandatory';
}
```

You can repeat this pattern for each field you'd like to check. You will need to assign `$custom_field1` and `$custom_field2` before you do this check (your script is doing this on the two lines after it checks to make sure `$error` is empty).

You may want to read through the PHP manual about [variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) and the [if statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).

Answer (score -2):

The most simple solution would be to create an array with the required fields and loop though them. This enables you to both check mandatory fields in a flexible way *and* have error messages for individual fields:

```
// required fields
$required = [
    'name' => 'Name',
    'email' => 'Emailaddress',
    'custom_field1' => 'My awesome field 1',
    'custom_field2' => 'My awesome field 2',
];

// list of errors
$errors = [];

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // loop through required fields
    foreach ($required as $key => $name) {
        if ($_POST[$key] !== '') {
            continue;
        }

        $errors[$key] = $name . ' is required';
    }
}

// check if there were errors
if (!empty($errors)) {
    // display errors
}
```

The advantage of this solution is that you can easily add more required field by simply adding it to the `$required` array.

You could even easily add other validation like that. For example:

```
// validation of fields
$validation= [
    'name' => [
        'name' => 'Name',
        'required' => true,
    ],
    'email' => [
        'name' => 'Emailaddress',
        'required' => true,
        'validation' => 'email',
    ],
    'custom_field1' => [
        'name' => 'My awesome field 1',
        'required' => true,
        'validation' => '/^[a-z]{2,}$/i',
     ],
    'custom_field2' => [
        'name' => 'My awesome field 2',
        'required' => true,
    ],
];

function validateEmail($key, $data, $errors) {
    if (!filter_var($_POST[$key], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors[$key] = $data['name'] . ' must be a valid emailaddress';
    }

    return $errors;
}

function validatePattern($key, $data, $errors) {
    if (preg_match($data['validation'], $_POST[$key]) !== 1) {
        $errors[$key] = $data['name'] . ' has an incorrect format';
    }

    return $errors;
}

// list of errors
$errors = [];

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // loop fields to be validated
    foreach ($validationas $key => $data) {
        if (array_key_exists('validation', $data)) {
            switch($data['validation']) {
                case 'email':
                    $errors = validateEmail($key, $data, $errors);
                    break;

                default:
                    validatePattern($key, $data, $errors)
                    break;
            }
        }

        if ($data['required'] !== true) {
            continue;
        }

        if ($_POST[$key] === '') {
            $errors[$key] = $data['name'] . ' is required';
        }
    }
}
```

You could also add client side validation as in [LMT-PhD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23188640/508666) but you should *always* have at least server side validation. Client side validation should be treated as a nice thing to do for users and nothing more.